# Qt - ActiveX - How to handle custom out-parameter?

Tags: c++, qt, activex, activeqt

Considering an `idl` defined like bellow:

```
interface IServerConnection : IDispatch {
    [id(1), helpstring("method IsConnected")] HRESULT IsConnected([out] BOOL* pVal);
};

interface IClientControl : IDispatch {
    [id(1), helpstring("method GetServerConnection")] HRESULT GetServerConnection([out] IServerConnection** ppServerConnection);
};
```

The `dumpcpp` generate code like bellow:

```cpp
class IServerConnection : public QAxObject
{
public:
    ...
    inline void IsConnected(int& pVal);
    ...
};


class ClientControl : public QAxWidget
{
public:
    ...

    ClientControl (IClientControl *iface)
    : QAxWidget()
    {
        initializeFrom(iface);
        delete iface;
    }

    inline void GetServerConnection(IServerConnection** ppServerConnection);
    ...
};
```

It returns type mismatch if I direct call `ClientControl::GetServerConnection`.

> QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member GetServerConnection: Type mismatch in parameter 0

How to get `IServerConnection` from the `ClientControl`?

---

With suggestion by @Remy Lebeau the `idl` changed to:

```
interface IServerConnection : IDispatch {
    [id(1), helpstring("method IsConnected")] HRESULT IsConnected([out] BOOL* pVal);
};

interface IClientControl : IDispatch {
    [id(1), helpstring("method GetServerConnection")] HRESULT GetServerConnection([out, retval] IServerConnection** ppServerConnection);
};
```

Then the source generated by `dumpcpp`:

```cpp
class ClientControl : public QAxWidget
{
public:
    ...
    inline IServerConnection* GetServerConnection();
    ...
};
```

By calling `GetServerConnection` like:

```cpp
ClientControl ctrl;
auto conn = ctrl.GetServerConnection();
```

It outputs:

> ```
> QVariantToVARIANT: out-parameter not supported for "subtype".
> QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member GetServerConnection: Member not found
> ```

Changing the source code or implementation behind the `idl` is impossible.
I can't change the interface to a return type, and that's another question.

It's more like a `Qt` problem rather than `idl`.

Comment: Please show your actual code that is getting the type mismatch error when trying to "direct call `ClientControl::GetServerConnection`". And FYI, in both methods shown, the `[out]` parameter should be marked as `[out, retval]` instead.

Comment: ``ClientControl::GetServerConnection`` is a member function, what do you mean by the actual code? I'm not familiar with `idl`, and it's provided by a sdk, I will try to find out how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: the `[out]` parameter of `IsConnected()` should also be `[out, retval]`

Comment: That is unused, and should not make any difference to my question.

Answer (score 1):

By using option `--compat`

> ```
> Options
>   ...
>   --compat        Treat all coclass parameters as IDispatch.
> ```

`dumpcpp` generate source like bellow:

```cpp
class ClientControl : public QAxWidget
{
public:
    ...
    inline void GetServerConnection(IDispatch** ppServerConnection);
    ...
};
```

The type of `IDispatch` can be handled by Qt.

`Qt` use `QVariant` to store and transfer arguments to `VARIANT` underneath, it handles `IUnknown` and `IDispatch` specially. `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is useless here, as the argument that the interface required is indeed a type(e.g. `IServerConnection`) derived from `IDispatch`, not the generated version, which is derived from `QAxObject`.